# Dapper : Reading directly nth item from the GridReader

Tags: dapper

This what i found in dapper blog

```
var sql = 
@"
select * from Customers where CustomerId = @id
select * from Orders where CustomerId = @id
select * from Returns where CustomerId = @id";

using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {id=selectedId}))
{
   var customer = multi.Read<Customer>().Single();      
   var returns = multi.Read<Return>().ToList();
   var orders = multi.Read<Order>().ToList();
   ...
}
```

My requirement is I want to directly read only "orders"    . Can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the other two, you can call `Read` without ever iterating that sequence: no objects will be materialized:

```
var customer = multi.Read<Customer>(); // not consumed
var returns = multi.Read<Return>(); // not consumed
var orders = multi.Read<Order>().ToList();
```

Comment: is there any way that I could avoid writing first 2 lines

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh I suppose we could add some kind of `Skip()` method, but currently: no. How would it know to skip them? You could use the non-generic API, though, i.e. `multi.Read();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Query extension to read single, e.g.

```
const string sql = "select * from Orders where CustomerId = @id";
var orders = connection.Query<Order>(sql, new {id = 1}).ToList();
```

Edit:

To execute stored procedure:

```
var orders = connection.Query<Order>("GetOrders", new {id = 1}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

Comment: I know this . but my actual sql is a stored procedure

Comment: I guess your question was unclear. I have edited my answer for SP as well.

Comment: but my first read is of type Customer not Order ? does this work?

Comment: I'm a little lost, your questions was: " I want to directly read only "orders"", but now the Customer is in play. Can you maybe edit your question to make it clear so we know what you are trying to do?

Comment: According to ma question my reader will have 3 item collections . first is of Customer . second is of Return and third is Order . Does your solution directly reads orders ? . even though my reader contains customer and return i dont want to read first 2 colections . I directly want to read third one .